# Webapi working locally but not when hosting with sub-domains

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, iis-7

I am building a simple webapi which retrieves customers balance from db.Everthing works well locally hosted in IIS.The api takes one param from the body.

```
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("MobileBankingApi", "v1/{controller}/{action}");   
    }
```

And the Action

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ActionName("balance")]
    public IHttpActionResult GetBalance([FromBody]Account account)
    {
        account.balance = BusinessLayer.Api.AccountHolderApi.GetBalance(account.accountNumber);
        return Ok(account);
    }
```

Locally works fine with this uri

> http://localhost/v1/accounts/balance

And when i deploy the build to a live server(IIS 7) with subdomain as

> http://api.mydomain.com/v1/accounts/balance

i get the 404 error.What i am doing wrong?Help appreciated.

Comment: Did you verify if POST verb is not blocked on the remote server? IIS Manager -> Default Website -> Request Filtering (Double Click) -> Http Verbs tab. You can also verify at the individual website as well

Comment: put a test page, like index.html, in the application's root. Can you bring it up in a browser at http://api.mydomain.com/index.html ?

Comment: @Crowcoder Hello sir..i did get the .html file response.

Comment: @Gururaj request filtering is installed sir..i am doing this in windows server 2008 r2

Comment: I meant, verify if POST request is disabled here.

Comment: @Gururaj sir i cant find any option where i could enable/disable post request in windows server 2008 server manager.

Comment: If the Http Verbs tab is empty then there is no filtering applied.

Comment: @Gururaj there is no such thing called Request Filtering in IIS manager of windows server 2008r2

Comment: @Crowcoder trying to fix this thing since hours doing helluva R&D..putting an index.html in the app root was showing up in browser..now it isnt..the api.mydomain.com pings well from the command promt but with api.mydomain.com/index.html gives 404.help please

Comment: I already looked over what I could and cannot find a problem with your code. It could be a DNS issue or misconfigured hosts file. The fact that the test page came up eliminated a lot of things but if that changed I just have no idea.

Comment: @Crowcoder any tips to get to the core of the problem sir?this thing is taking my hairs away

Comment: If the test page never worked I would say you have IIS setup differently than you think you do. So, are you sure it worked? In IIS select your site/application, over in the Actions section click the "Browse... on..." link. what do you get?

Comment: @Crowcoder i want to get this fixed sir so here is the detail.i was on a different network when this api.mydomain.com/index.html worked..to be precise i was in my workplace..mydomain.com is hosted with a provider and IP is indeed static..the subdomain api.mydomain.com is hosted in my workplace server(windows 2008r2)..like you said to include and check index.html in root of the app it worked while i was in my workplace..i am accesing the live server now and at localhost binding its serving the page index.html and not in api.planetearthsolution.com.index.html.getting 404 error

Comment: Ok, I think its clear this is not a code issue. I'm not really an admin so maybe you should try posting on https://serverfault.com/ and describe your setup in detail.

Comment: @Crowcoder Thank you for your time sir.Will do that.